# bitnami/phppgadmin: Gives Bad request. Nothing found in the error_log

Tags: docker, bitnami, error-log, phppgadmin

I am using a docker-compose file for postgresql and phppgadmin as follows:

I have

```
  postgresql:
    image: "postgres:13-alpine"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: project
      POSTGRES_USER: django
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: django
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    networks:
      - postgresql_network

  phppgadmin:
    image: "bitnami/phppgadmin:7.13.0"
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: "postgresql"
      DATABASE_SSL_MODE: "disable"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - postgresql_network
    ports:
      - 80:8080
```

If I am running this on localhost, I can connect to the site. That is `http://localhost` and everything works well

But If I am on server say some ip address: xx.xx.xx.xx and try to connect `http://xx.xx.xx.xx`

then it says

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I found the vhost as:

```
$ cat /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

# Let Apache know we're behind a SSL reverse proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
</VirtualHost>

Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf"
```

and also the `phppgadmin-vhost.conf`

```
$ cat /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/phppgadmin-vhost.conf 
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080 _default_:8080>
  ServerAlias *
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/phppgadmin
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/phppgadmin">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And i found the logs as:

```
$ ls -al /opt/bitnami/apache/logs
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 16 01:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 16 01:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Aug 16 01:25 access_log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Aug 16 01:25 error_log -> /dev/stderr
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan  1  1970 pagespeed_log
```

Here I dont see any errors in the error_log

And in my docker compose i see

```
phppgadmin_1  | 172.29.0.4 - - [17/Aug/2021:04:23:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 347
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Developer here

Are you accessing to the port **80** or the port **8080**? Please note the container is listening in the port **8080** and it's possible you're not doing the port mapping in the remote server as you did locally using Docker Compose.

Could you add the environment variable **PHPPGADMIN_ALLOW_REMOTE_CONNECTIONS=yes** to the "phppgadmin" container in your docker-compose.yaml?

Finally, please also share the content of the vhost **/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/phppgadmin-vhost.conf** if you're still struggling with it.

Comment: I am using `8080` only

Comment: `PHPPGADMIN_ALLOW_REMOTE_CONNECTIONS=yes` - What is this for. Because when i use it on localhost it works well. I am connecting to a remote postgresql server only

Comment: So you're actually connecting to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080, am I right? The `PHPPGADMIN_ALLOW_REMOTE_CONNECTIONS` is necessary to add the Apache directive `Require all granted` to the associated virtual host.

Comment: I am connecting to 8080. also updated the question with `phppgadmin-vhost.conf`

Comment: Also how to check whats the error or logs. I am clueless

Comment: Can you reproduced the issue when using a simple `curl`? Sth like: `curl http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/`
Please also double-check you're using `http://` instead of `https://`